# My jQuery array isn't numerically indexed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I select a group of elements in my DOM like so:

```
var menu_items = $('#ubermenu-nav-main-0-primary > li a span')
       .not('#ubermenu-nav-main-0-primary > li ul li a span');

menu_items.each(function(i){
    var strings = [];
    strings.push = this.innerHTML;
    console.log(strings);  
});
```

After pushing all the elements to my array - I really want the array numerically indexed but what I actually get looks like:

[image: console]

Something is not quite right?

Comment: you are reseting the `strings` array each time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get node text into an array, consider using [jQuery's `.map()`](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=map). Like so:

```
var menu_items = $('#ubermenu-nav-main-0-primary > li a span')
       .not('#ubermenu-nav-main-0-primary > li ul li a span');

var strings = menu_items.map (function (){
    return this.innerHTML.trim ();
} ).get ();
console.log (strings);
```

**Note:**

1. When getting text from a page, you almost always want to `trim` the leading and trailing whitespace.
2. You probably want to use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`.

Comment: This did work returning an object with my menu items in it.

Comment: See the edited answer.  Tack on the `.get()` to return an array.

Answer (score 1):

Do not overwrite the array in each iteration, take its declaration outside on  `each()` loop:

```
var strings = [];
menu_items.each(function(i){
    strings.push(this.innerHTML);
     console.log(strings);  
});
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. I ended up with an array with one element in it (Contact) with an index of `push`

Comment: Sorry, I have copied your mistake, did not noticed it. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
var menu_items = $('#ubermenu-nav-main-0-primary > li a span')
   .not('#ubermenu-nav-main-0-primary > li ul li a span');

var strings = [];
menu_items.each(function(i){
    strings.push = this.innerHTML;
    console.log(strings);  
});
```

You need to set the strings array outside of the each loop.

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues, redefining the array on every iteration and using a key instead of the push method.

```
var strings = [];  //<-- defined outside
menu_items.each(function(i){
    strings.push(this.innerHTML);  //<-- push is a method
     console.log(strings);  
});
```

Or the way I would do it

```
var strings = menu_items.each(function(ind, elem){ return elem.innerHTML; }).get();
```

Comment: Brilliant - I now have an array rather than an object. Many thanks epascarello.

Comment: Nice. I need to target the first word in each array value (needle in haystack)  making it bold text. But maybe that's another question.